Does flight from US to Japan using Canadian airline satisfy the Fly American Act?
I recently had a trip from the US to Japan with a connecting flight in Canada. I didn't know I would have to follow the Fly American Act when I had purchased the flight, and am wondering if anyone knows if I would qualify for the 5th exception?
I know that there is no city pair fare between the two airports I flew to and from.
I chose the flight I did based on the cost, whatever was cheapest. So I don't quality for 1. There were flights that would've been more than 24 hours, but I chose a 17.5 hour trip so I don't qualify for 2. There were US carrier flights that are not direct and have two transfers outside the US, but I didn't choose those flights. But I'm guessing there were other US carrier options that didn't have this issue and cost a tiny bit more than the flight I chose.

Thanks in advance!

If the shortest available flight on a US carrier was 23.5 hours then you would meet the conditions for exception 3.

Why are you worried about cost if the fare will be charged to the government?  You should mostly be worried about time, for which the government will also likely be paying for.

What you've all said makes sense. I appreciate it!

Note: Ticket cost and convenience are NOT exceptions to the Fly America Act. - it says so right there.
There's such an agreement with Japan, but you seem to be required to use a Japanese flag carrier to be able to use it based on certain conditions:

The agreements with Australia, Switzerland, and Japan permit the use of an Australian, Swiss, or Japanese air carrier for international travel between the U.S. and these countries as long as a "City Pair" fare is not available between the cities of origin and destination.

If you bought the flight through the Japanese airline, then maybe you can use this exception. There are other conditions down the page to be able to use any exception, which I suspect you can no longer fulfill.

thank you so much for this information and confirmation!
